# Qu'est-ce que signifie « Ça craint » ?

Tags: usage, registre-familier

Qu'est ce-que signifie cette expression et dans quel cas est-elle utilisée? J’imagine qu'il s'agit d'une expression plutôt familière mais je n'arrive pas a bien comprendre sa signification.

Comment: "Au nord de Paris, ça craint trop. Je préfère éviter d'y aller." C'est utilisé pour parler d'un lieu où l'on risque de se faire agresser / attaquer / voler. C'est une expression très courante.

Answer (score 12):

*Version francophone*

L'expression, en effet familière, n'a qu'un rapport indirect avec le sens courant du verbe *craindre*, qui n'avait pas à l'origine pour vocation d'être employé dans une tournure impersonnelle.

Elle peut signifier plusieurs choses, toujours négatives :

- signaler un **danger** modéré, une **situation épineuse**, voire simplement un **souci**
- exprimer son **découragement, mécontentement**, son **ennui**, ou sa **déception** face à la faible qualité d'une production, d'une oeuvre, d'un résultat

---

*English reader version*

The usual translation for it in English is **It sucks**.

As in English, it can be used when someone faces:

- a danger or more often a mild threat;
- something boring or otherwise disappointing qualitatively;
- more generally something meaning that **trouble is coming**...

Comment: Danger ou menace immédiate, je ne vois pas. Un exemple ?

Comment: J'avais écrit la partie anglaise en premier et je me suis (un comble!) mal auto-traduit ! Mais en effet *immédiate* est trop fort. De même, j'entendais *danger* dans un sens soit métaphorique soit pour un danger modéré. Je vois assez mal quelqu'un dire *Ca craint* en se retournant au milieu de la route pour apercevoir un 33 tonnes roulant vers lui à toute vitesse... je corrige pour atténuer.

Comment: Il y a aussi des situations ou l'on peut le rapprocher de 'ça pue', c'est à dire que la loyauté, la transparence, l'élégance ne sont pas de mise. "Les manip' du parti adverse ça craint" : les méthodes utilisées ne sont pas loyales, voire illégales ; ou plus franchouillard "Pincer les fesses de la Baronne, ça craint".

Answer (score 7):

En plus des significations génériques apportées par le poste de Romain Valeri, cette expression est parfois employée dans un cas spécifique : pour parler du sentiment d'insécurité que l'on ressent dans un lieu.

Exemple : Dans ce quartier de la ville, après 22H, ça craint.

Dans ce contexte particulier, cette expression devient très familière, je déconseille de l'utiliser.

Comment: Mais le coeur de la question n'était pas de traduire, et n'impliquait pas l'anglais, meme si c'est en effet un plus à apporter.

Comment: Effectivement pour l'Anglais... Désolé, réflex de SO. Il est conseillé faire l'intégralité de la réponse en Français ici ?

Comment: @tvuillemin Faire la réponse en français est souhaitable, tous les lecteurs ne connaissent pas toujours les subtilités de l'anglais (et ne sont pas forcément anglophone) ; sinon le faire dans la langue que l'on écrit le mieux (dans les deux si l'on est bilingue)

Comment: Quoi qu'il en soit, ta remarque est juste (+1), c'est également un emploi courant du terme à ne pas oublier.

Comment: "très familière" Il faut pas exagérer... C'est une expression extrêmement courante. Mais, effectivement, ce n'est pas du français littéraire. Donc, c'est à déconseiller uniquement dans le cas où l'on voudrait écrire un roman (et encore)....